# sshd: Could not load host key

Tags: networking, server, ssh, sshd

Running `/usr/sbin/sshd` produces the following results:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd
```

I checked in `/etc/ssh` and all 4 host keys (and their `.pub` files) seem to be available, although `/var/run/sshd` is missing.

What can I do to let it load the host keys?

Comment: I encountered this when I had some syntax errors in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd
```

If you still get the privilege separation directory error:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd && sudo chmod -R 755 /var/run/sshd
```